# How whatsapp is loading weblink contents in chat so fastly?

Tags: android, web

When we share or copy paste a link to whatsapp chat it's content is loading immediately. But loading such content in a webview may make it slow and less responsive. But in whatsapp no such problems are visible. How they are achieving this?
[image]

Comment: how would you know whatsapp using `WebView` and not `Acitivity` ?

Comment: Are we talking just about the link preview as shown in the screenshot? Data for the preview is being fetched while you're still typing the message, and is presumably stored with the message content.

Comment: @sushildlh I dont know. I just want to know how they are doing it.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Yes just the link preview as show in the screenshot. Could you please explain how to do that.

Comment: That is not a WebView, but it is combined TextViews and ImageView. The data is fetched from server using the website's metadatas

Comment: @Arunkrishna: when you type a message, as soon as your WhatsApp client identifies that you've typed a URL, a request is sent to WhatsApp servers to pre-fetch metadata for that URL. You'll know this is the case becuase you can see the preview show up already in your not-yet-sent message. This is where the latency occurs. It does take a while to show up, but you won't notice, as WhatsApp has no indication to let you know it's looking for such data.